# Unable to launch cropping window using react-native-image-picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I need to launch the cropping window using react-native-image picker. But the below-mentioned code snippet not worked for me. Any suggestions

```
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response)  => {
        if (response.didCancel) {
          console.warn('Cancel photo picker');
        }
        else if (response.error) {
          console.warn('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        }
        else {
          console.warn('ImagePicker no Error: ', response.error);
          ImagePicker.openCropper({
            path: response,
            width: deviceWidth,
            height: deviceWidth*5/4,
            cropperToolbarTitle: '',
            hideBottomControls: true,
            enableRotationGesture: true,
            avoidEmptySpaceAroundImage:true
         }).then(image => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('ShowAllCroppedImage', {uri: response.uri, croppedImage: this.croppedImage.bind(this)});
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("openCropper error = " + err)
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting ImagePicker no Error warning?

Comment: Yes, I am getting no error warning

Comment: I don't see any api for `openCropper`. Can you link me which image-picker are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong library. The library you are using doesn't support cropping features.

Use [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) for selecting image from library and then cropping it.

Comment: I have used react-native-image-crop-picker (open cropper). Here I am getting ilegal call back invocation error

Comment: @sejn If you are using correct library, then there is no `launchImageLibrary` api in that library.

Comment: Yes, that correct. My scenario is launching library in a class and redirecting to other screen and opening the cropping window from the launched library image.

Answer (score 0):

Image cropper doesn't trigger because launchImageLibrary animation is still ending. With the picker modal still open, cropper modal fails to open correctly. If you want to use both libraries like this, you should call a separate function within launchImageLibrary callback. This function should use setTimeout and wait ~500ms, and then launch ImagePicker.OpenCropper. That is how we use both of these libraries successfully.